# Is there a way to convert a YAML file to a JSON file in Gitlab-ci file?

Tags: json, bash, yaml, gitlab-ci

I am trying to convert an api-sepc.yml file to a JSON file in gitlab-ci. I know you can use yq but I am having trouble installing yq in the gitlab-ci file and I keep getting the error "Unable to locate package yq". I had no problem installing jq but when I try doing yq I get that error. If there is another method or if you know how to install yq please let me know.

I tried this because it worked when installing jq
'''

- apt-get -qq update
- apt-get install -y yq
  '''

I also tried this

- apt-get -qq update
- apt-get install software-properties-common -y
- add-apt-repository ppa:rmescandon/yq
- apt-get install -y yq

In both instances I get the error "Unable to locate package yq". I was doing these in a before_script for some reason stack overflow converted the "-" to dots in each line.

Comment: What `image:` are you running? Also, test it locally, with docker first, will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `apt-get -qq update` after `add-apt-repository ppa:rmescandon/yq`. Otherwise it won't fetch the package list from the added repository.